# R referencing other rows within a dataframe

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe df:

```
 indx adj_coords explore_ind
1    1    2, 3, 4        dark
2    2    1, 3, 5        dark
3    3    1, 2, 4       light
4    4    1, 3, 5        dark
5    5    1, 4, 5       light
    
    df<-structure(list(indx = 1:5, adj_coords = list(2:4, c(1L, 3L, 5L), c(1L, 2L, 4L), c(1L, 3L, 5L), c(1L, 4L, 5L)), explore_ind = c("dark", 
"dark", "light", "dark", "light")), row.names = c(NA, 
    5L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to add another column called adj_coords_explore_ind that tells us whether the row given in the adj_cord is dark or light. The result would look something like:

```
 indx adj_coords explore_ind     adj_coords_explore_ind
1    1    2, 3, 4        dark    dark, light, dark
2    2    1, 3, 5        dark    dark, light, light
3    3    1, 2, 4       light    dark, dark, dark
4    4    1, 3, 5        dark    dark, light, light
5    5    1, 4, 5       light    dark, dark, light
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
df$adj_coords_explore_ind <- map(df$adj_coords, ~ df$explore_ind[.x])
```

Answer (score 1):

One option could be:

```
within(df, adj_coords_explore_ind <- lapply(adj_coords, function(x) explore_ind[match(x, indx)]))

  indx adj_coords explore_ind adj_coords_explore_ind
1    1    2, 3, 4        dark      dark, light, dark
2    2    1, 3, 5        dark     dark, light, light
3    3    1, 2, 4       light       dark, dark, dark
4    4    1, 3, 5        dark     dark, light, light
5    5    1, 4, 5       light      dark, dark, light
```